# How can I include `mpirun -n` in VSCode for launching the executable?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mpi

I'm using Visual Studio Code, and I am using MPI in my `c` code. Compiling is not an issue, but after compilation, it runs the program and I would like to change the default behaviour for that. I'd like to have it do `mpirun -n 2 {fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}`.

My launch.json file looks as follows, but doesn't work as intended, i.e. it runs the program after compilation, but does not use 2 processes.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "mpicc - Build and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "args": [
        "-n 2",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "TMPDIR",
          "value": "/tmp"
        }
      ],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "preLaunchTask": "mpicc build active file"
    }
  ]
}
```

In case it is actually not the `launch.json` that is responsible, here is my `tasks.json` (compiling works fine, though):

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "MPIcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/mpicc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-lm",
                "-O3",
                "-Wall",
                "-std=c99"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Why did you do `"-n 2"` instead of `"-n", "2"`? There's a difference. What you did passes it as a single string argument to the program. The second passes it as two separate string args to the program. Some programs will account for user weirdnesses like this, but does the program you wrote do that?

Comment: I tried both, neither worked as expected. But thank you for pointing that out!